# Почему @Entity класс не может быть final в JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

Есть множество требований к классам которые могут быть объявлены как  @Entity, и одно из требований - это то, что класс не может быть обьявлен как final, почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение своего вопроса:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472438/why-cant-entity-class-in-jpa-be-final
В статье говорится о том что реализации механизмов JPA создают подклассы наших Entity классов для различных проверок, а поскольку класс обьявлен как final, то от него просто нельзя будет унаследоваться.